# Airflow jinja2 templated json file

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I am using Airflow 1.10.1 with Python 3.5 and let's say I extended `BaseOperator` operator and added `.json` extension to `template_ext`

```py
template_ext = ('.json',)
```

and then I provide a path to the `.json` template file containing macro placeholders

```
{
  "kind": "dfareporting#report",
  "name": "{{ params.cm_report_name }}"
}
```

which has placeholder for `params` parameter that is passed to all dag operators via `default_args`.

```py
args = {
    # ...
    'params': {
        'cm_report_name': "AAAA"
    }
}
```

But for some reason my macro doesn't get substituted with "AAAA".

I tried to copy/paste pattern that [bigquery_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.1/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L96-L98) is using for `.sql` files.

Here is the full code of the operator: https://gist.github.com/fpopic/64455b8d24acc6a7d3e6d73392b20c9f#file-cm_report_find_update_operator-py-L15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "template_fields" parameter, like a follow:

```
template_fields = ('sql', 'destination_dataset_table', 'labels')
template_ext = ('.sql', )
```

Comment: but even if I put `template_fields = ('params')` it doesn't work.

Comment: template_fields should be the the fields containing the templated strings, not the values. In your case, the filed that contains your json file path

Comment: Worked by adding`template_fields = ('report_file_path', )`. Thanks!